Deploying Nextjs typscript using app/src directory on aws windows server with iis & iisnode
After 9 Hours I have successfully shown the first page (entry point of my project).
but in the browser tab, I am seeing my server.js code. not the rendered pages.

This is my server.js code which is also showing on the browser.

const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
 createServer(async (req, res) => {
  try {
   // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
   // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
   const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
  const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

  if (pathname === '/a') {
    await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
  } else if (pathname === '/b') {
    await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
  } else {
    await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
  res.statusCode = 500
  res.end('internal server error')
   }
 })
   .once('error', (err) => {
   console.error(err)
   process.exit(1)
  })
  .listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
  })
})


This is my web.config file

 <configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!--
    All appSettings are made available to your Node.js app via environment 
    variables
    You can access them in your app through the process.env object.            
      process.env.<key>       -->
   <add key="NEXT_PUBLIC_WAITINGLIST_URL" value="http://localhost:8017/api/" />
  <add key="WAITINGLIST_URL" value="http://localhost:8017/api/" />
 <add key="DATABASE_URL" value="somevalue" />
   <add key="AUTH_SECRET" value="somevalue" />
    </appSettings>
     <system.webServer>
        <iisnode node_env="production"
             nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"
             maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
             maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="100"
             namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="250"
             maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
             maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
             asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
             initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
             maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
             uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000"
             gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
             loggingEnabled="true"
             logDirectory="iisnode"
             debuggingEnabled="true"
             debugHeaderEnabled="false"
             debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
             debuggerPathSegment="debug"
             maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
             maxTotalLogFileSizeInKB="1024"
             maxLogFiles="20"
             devErrorsEnabled="true"
             flushResponse="false"
             enableXFF="false"
             promoteServerVars=""
             configOverrides="iisnode.yml"
             watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"
 nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" 
interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;"
            />

<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
    </rule>

    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the 
      /public folder -->
    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
    </rule>

    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>

<!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <add segment="node_modules"/>
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>

<!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
 </system.webServer>

i think issue is only with my web.config file. i have used this link for link nextjs azureextension. also I have used multiple toturials like Ardi from youtube,dipendra from medium, john from medium and couple of links from stack overflow.

also added node server.js in start script of package.json.

Your server.js file is responsible for handling all dynamic routing, but static files (such as stylesheets, scripts, etc.) may not be routed correctly. This may be an issue with the rewrite rules in your web.config file.
